# How to remove an element of a vector from within a function in R

Tags: r, vector

Is it possible to alter a vector in an R function without explicitly returning the vector and replacing the old one? I have the following function which simulates drawing a card from a deck, I'd like for the card drawn to be removed from the deck, but the following leaves it unaltered.

```
draw_card <- function(deck) {
  card <- sample(deck, 1)
  remove_card <- sample(which(deck==card))
  deck[-remove_card]
  card
}
```

Comment: What is your `remove_card` supposed to be doing? isn't the card to be removed already stored in `card`?

Comment: One way is to return a list consisting of the updated deck and the card.  That way you can have the updated deck without messing with the original deck or environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the dangerous `<<-` operator is your friend. It has environmental complications though, this will work if the deck is in the parent environment, but if there's no deck there, it will look in higher and higher level environments until it finds one.

```
draw_card <- function(deck) {
  card <- sample(deck, 1)
  remove_card <- sample(which(deck==card))
  deck <<- deck[-remove_card]
  card
}
```

EDIT: However, if you're doing this kind of OOP, I think you should probably take a look at R6 classes, you can create a deck object and then have `draw_card` be a method which updates the deck by reference

Here's an R6 class, for example, which does what you want:

```
library(R6)
deck <-
 R6Class('deck',
      public = 
        list(
          cards = list(),
          initialize =
            function(cards) {
              self$cards <- cards
            },
          drawCard =
            function() {
              card <- sample(self$cards,1)
              self$cards <- setdiff(self$cards,card)
              card
            }
        ))

 #Make a new object with:
 newDeck <- deck$new(1:52)
 #Start Drawing Cards
 newDeck$drawCard()
 newDeck$drawCard()
 # Check remaining deck, notice the cards you've drawn are missing:
 newDeck$cards
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I'll probably use <<- for now, but I'm definitely going to take a look at R6 classes too.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
## initialise the deck
deck <- 1:52

## remove a random card from the deck
set.seed(123)
deck <- deck[-sample(deck, 1)]
## or, if you're not using 1:52
## deck <- deck[deck != deck[sample(deck, 1)] ]

## record which cards have been removed
removed_card <- 1:52[!1:52 %in% deck]

deck
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
# [40] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52

removed_card
# [1] 15
```